# Forwarding old emails

Tags: linux, windows, email, forwarding

I'm trying to forward a series of old emails from one email address to another, both are Microsoft email accounts. The thing is that i don't what to simply forward them using the web interface, that creates a "wrapper email" that contains the original message.

From what I understand of the email protocol there is a chain of "Received:" headers that contains the servers where the email passed by. I just want to forward them to the new email as if they were forwarded if the fist place if I had configured my inbox to do so (maintaining all the "attributes" including from, to, subject etc).

From what I searched, I think that this can be done by a program that connects to the POP and SMTP server of the old inbox and forwards the emails to the new inbox.

I tried using the the gnu tool **movemail** but there is a problem when specifying the original pop server, the syntax is **pop://user:pass@popserver:port**. When using an Microsoft email (the email address is the username): **pop://blablabla@hotmail.com:mypass@pop3.live.com** the program fails because there is two @ signs on the parameter (using %40 does no help).

Then I tried **fetchmail** I could not get it to work because it does not support SSL on the SMTP connection only on the POP, the Microsoft POP and SMTP servers both require a secure connection.

Is there any other way of doing this? Using some other tool for lixux or windows?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually handle these kinds of things is to set one account as POP3 and the other account as IMAP with the mail client application of my choice (ie Thunderbird or Outlook).

Source account - POP3
Destination account - IMAP

I'll download all of the mail from the POP3 account and then copy it over to the IMAP account. The IMAP account will synchonize with the mail server, uploading my other account's emails to my new main account.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could push emails to the server using IMAP, thanks for the tip. Anyway Outlook/Hotmail does not yet support IMAP (if ever will), maybe I should change my main email provider.

Comment: For Outlook 2013, Exchange ActiveSync support is built in. Just enter the email address and password and it should configure automatically. For Outlook 2010, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2003, you still need to use the free Outlook Hotmail Connector add-in.

Comment: I was not referring to Outlook "the program" I was referring Outlook.com (the new Hotmail.com). I want to push emails to an Outlook account (blabla@outlook.com) and it does not yet support IMAP.

Comment: Correct. I meant that you cannot use IMAP with Outlook.com but rather Exchange ActiveSync which Outlook 2013 natively supports. If using an older version of Outlook then you would need the Outlook Hotmail Connector add-in to connect to Outlook.com via Exchange ActiveSync.